# Error in SQL query using Where

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

Im trying to make an query that shows the adresses with the **ZIP of 1391, 1393, 1396, 1426, 1427 and all the zips between 3400 and 3433.**

```
SELECT ZIP, HOUSE_NR, APPARTMENT_NR, VerzBedrag
FROM werkelijke_inboedels
WHERE ProductLine = 'inboedel'
AND Product_Option = 'Inboedel All Risk' OR 'Inboedel Extra Uitgebreid'
AND ZIP = %'1391'% OR %'1393'% OR %'1396'% OR %'1426'% OR %'1427'%
AND ZIP > %'3400'%
AND ZIP < %'4133'%
```

Can someone change the query in the right one?

Comment: why are you wildcarding the ZIP search?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only need to use `IN` and `BETWEEN` to work the query as expected. *Pattern matching is not needed here.*

```
SELECT  *
FROM    tableName
WHERE   ProductLine = 'inboedel' AND 
        Product_Option IN ('Inboedel All Risk','Inboedel Extra Uitgebreid') AND
        (
            ZIP IN (1391, 1393, 1396, 1426, 1427) OR
            ZIP BETWEEN 3400 AND 3433
        )
```

Comment: The OP doesn't actually want a `LIKE`. A plain `IN` without the `%` should do just fine

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes you're right. It just needs `IN` and `BETWEEN`

Comment: It does not work.. In the result I also get also ZIP codes bigger than 4133 and smaller than 3400

Comment: have you tried my updated one. the first query i posted did not group the `OR` condition.

Comment: you're welcome `:D` by the way, What [RDBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system) you are using? `RDBMS` stands for *Relational Database Management System*. `RDBMS is the basis for SQL`, and for all modern database systems like MS SQL Server, IBM DB2, Oracle, MySQL, etc...

Comment: don't forget to use correct data types. when dealing with numbers use numeric data types rather that strings `:D`

Answer (score 4):

```
AND ZIP IN ('1391', '1393', '1396', '1426', '1427')
OR  ZIP BETWEEN  '3400' AND '4133'
```

Comment: yeah. I can't see why they're needed anyway

Comment: running between on strings is risky business :) Avoid it like the plague.

Comment: _should_ be fine if they're all 4-'digit' zips

Answer (score 0):

wild cards go inside of quotes:

```
'%1391%'
```

These are used with the LIKE operator.